# Stats test to compare two distributions of proportions?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference

I am struggling for a statistical test to compare two distributions of proportions i.e. my control group and experimental group.  Exp design is as follows:

40 samples (1 sample = 1 tree) each for control and experimental group.

Each sample is 10 yes/no recordings per tree.

10 recordings x 40 trees = 400 recordings for experimental and 400 for control.

I take the proportion of "yes" answers per tree for all 40 samples. Thus I am left with 40 proportions for control and 40 proportions for experimental. I want to compare for a statistically significant difference.

```
tree1  k1   k2   k3   k4   k5   k6   k7   k8   k9   k10   proportion
       yes  no   no   yes  yes  yes  no   yes  yes  no    0.6
.
.
.
tree40 k1   k2   k3   k4   k5   k6   k7   k8   k9   k10   proportion
       yes  yes  no   yes  no   no   no   yes  yes  no    0.5
```

I've been told I can use a chi-square test to compare these, and I've also seen using a z-test. However I believe a z-test would be suitable if I were comparing two of these samples, for example, but not two distributions of many proportions. A z-test also requires normally distributed observations (I believe) which my test would violate since all the proportions are bound between 0 and 1. At this stage I'm unsure whether to take the average proportion for control/experimental and compare (but again, would need to allow for the bounding in comparing mean proportions) or can I somehow compare 400 bernoulli trials for each group? I'm beginning to think it is a case for [logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237104/compare-two-unpaired-samples-each-with-multiple-proportions)

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Do you care about which k are yeses? For instance, of everyone in T has k1-k5 set to yes and k6-k10 set to no, with the opposite pattern in Control, would you say there is no difference?

Comment: Which k are yeses is not a concern - only how many (x/10)

Comment: I would use logistic regression